# URL Access of the Resources files without typing its string directory

Tags: c#, url, resources

So I want to access files from the Resources folder, without typing its exact directory using a string because it's going to mess up the program if I run it on a different computer. This is the code that works:

```
var select = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
select.URL = @"C:\select.wav";
```

But I want to access the directory above by not typing its exact location. The code that I tried is this:

```
var select = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
select.URL = Properties.Resources.select.ToString();
```

But I think it's just converting it exactly to string word-by-word.
Is it possible to access the Resources using the .URL property without exactly typing the exact directory like the first code above?
thanks.

Comment: in the code: Properties.Resources.select.ToString();
select is the file that I'm trying to access. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Properties.Settings` instead of `Properties.Resources`.

Go to the Settings (not the resources) in the Properties in the solution explorer and add setting (lets name select) and then:

```
var select = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
select.URL = Properties.Settings.select;
```